# How to Parse the MLB Team and Player data using Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing, web-scraping

I am still learning and could use some help. I would like to parse the starting pitchers and their respective teams.

I would like the data in a Pandas Dataframe but do not know how to parse the data correctly. Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks for your time!

Here is an example of the desired output:

```
Game   Team     Name

       OAK     Chris Bassitt
1
       ARI     Zac Gallen


       SEA     Justin Dunn
2
       LAD     Ross Stripling
```

Here is my code:

```
#url = https://www.baseball-reference.com/previews/index.shtml

#Data needed: 1) Team  2) Pitcher Name

import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.baseball-reference.com/previews/index.shtml'

test = pd.read_html(url)

for t in test:
    name = t[1]
    team = t[0]
   
    print(team)
   
    print(name)
```

I feel like I have to create a Pandas DataFrame and append the Team and Name, however, I am not sure how to parse out just the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `pandas.read_html` returns a list of all the tables for a given URL
- dataframes in the list can be selected using normal list slicing and selecting methods

```py
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.baseball-reference.com/previews/index.shtml'

list_of_dataframes = pd.read_html(url)

# select and combine the dataframes for games; every other dataframe from 0 (even)
games = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes[0::2])

# display(games.head())
                 0   1        2
0      Cubs (13-6) NaN  Preview
1  Cardinals (4-4) NaN  12:00AM
0  Cardinals (4-4) NaN  Preview
1      Cubs (13-6) NaN   5:15PM
0   Red Sox (6-16) NaN  Preview

# select the players from list_of_dataframes; every other dataframe from 1 (odd)
players = list_of_dataframes[1::2]

# add the Game to the dataframes
for i, df in enumerate(players, 1):
    df['Game'] = i
    players[i-1] = df

# combine all the dataframe
players = pd.concat(players).reset_index(drop=True)

# create a players column for the name only
players['name'] = players[1].str.split('(', expand=True)[0]

# rename the colume
players.rename(columns={0: 'Team'}, inplace=True)

# drop 1
players.drop(columns=[1], inplace=True)

# display(players.head(6))
  Team  Game               name
0  CHC     1       Tyson Miller
1  STL     1         Alex Reyes
2  STL     2     Kwang Hyun Kim
3  CHC     2     Kyle Hendricks
4  BOS     3       Martin Perez
5  NYY     3  Jordan Montgomery
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much for this insight! Very informative... I will learn a lot from this.

Comment: I am so grateful for your response, sir @TrentonMcKinney. Brilliant work! =)

Answer (score 1):

Love those sports reference.com sites. Trenton's solution is perfect, so don't change the accepted answer, but just wanted to throw this alternative data source for probable pitchers incase you were interested.

Looks like mlb.com has a publicly available api to pull that info (I'm going to assume that's possibly where baseball-reference fills their probable pitcher page). But what I like about this is you can get much more data returned to analyse, and it gives you the option to get a wider date range to get historical data, and possibly probable pitchers 2 or 3 days in advance (as well as day of). So give this code a look over too, play with it, practice with it.

But this could set you up to your first machine learning sort of thing.

PS: Let me know if you figure out what `strikeZoneBottom` and `strikeZoneTop` means here if you even bother to look into this data. I haven't been able to figure out what those mean.

I'm also wondering too, if there's data regarding the ballpark. Like in the pitchers stats there's the fly ball:ground ball ratio. If there was data on the ballparks like if you have flyball pitcher in a venue that yields lots of homeruns, that you might see a different situation for that same pitcher in a ballpark where flyballs don't quite travel as far, or the stadium has deeper fences (essentially homeruns turn into warning track fly out and vice versa)??

**Code:**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

url = 'https://statsapi.mlb.com/api/v1/schedule'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}

yesterday = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(1), '%Y-%m-%d')
today = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d')
tomorrow = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() + timedelta(1), '%Y-%m-%d') 

#To get 7 days earlier; notice the minus sign
#pastDate = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(7), '%Y-%m-%d')

#To get 3 days later; notice the plus sign
#futureDate = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() + timedelta(3), '%Y-%m-%d')

#hydrate parameter is to get back certain data elements. Not sure how to alter it exactly yet, would have to play around
#But without hydrate, it doesn't return probable pitchers
payload = {
'sportId': '1',
'startDate': today, #<-- Change these to get a wider range of games (to also get historical stats for machine learning)
'endDate': today, #<-- Change these to get a wider range of games (to possible probable pitchers for next few days. just need to adjust timedelta above)
'hydrate': 'team(leaders(showOnPreview(leaderCategories=[homeRuns,runsBattedIn,battingAverage],statGroup=[pitching,hitting]))),linescore(matchup,runners),flags,liveLookin,review,broadcasts(all),venue(location),decisions,person,probablePitcher,stats,homeRuns,previousPlay,game(content(media(featured,epg),summary),tickets),seriesStatus(useOverride=true)'}

jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
dates = jsonData['dates']

rows = []
for date in dates:
    games = date['games']
    for game in games:
        dayNight = game['dayNight']
        gameDate = game['gameDate']
        city = game['venue']['location']['city']
        venue = game['venue']['name']
        teams = game['teams']
        for k, v in teams.items():
            row = {}
            
            row.update({'dayNight':dayNight, 
                    'gameDate':gameDate, 
                    'city':city, 
                    'venue':venue})
            
            homeAway = k
            teamName = v['team']['name']
            
            if 'probablePitcher' not in v.keys():
                row.update({'homeAway':homeAway,
                           'teamName':teamName})
                rows.append(row)
                
            else:
                probablePitcher = v['probablePitcher']
                fullName = probablePitcher['fullName']
                pitchHand = probablePitcher['pitchHand']['code']
                strikeZoneBottom = probablePitcher['strikeZoneBottom']
                strikeZoneTop = probablePitcher['strikeZoneTop']
                
                row.update({'homeAway':homeAway,
                           'teamName':teamName, 
                           'probablePitcher':fullName,
                           'pitchHand':pitchHand,
                           'strikeZoneBottom':strikeZoneBottom,
                           'strikeZoneTop':strikeZoneTop})
                
                stats = probablePitcher['stats']
                for stat in stats:
                    if stat['type']['displayName'] == 'statsSingleSeason' and stat['group']['displayName'] == 'pitching':
                        playerStats = stat['stats']
                        
                        row.update(playerStats)
                        rows.append(row)
                    
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**Output: First 10 rows**

```
print (df.head(10).to_string())
   airOuts  atBats  balks  baseOnBalls  blownSaves  catchersInterference  caughtStealing         city  completeGames dayNight  doubles  earnedRuns    era              gameDate  gamesFinished  gamesPitched  gamesPlayed  gamesStarted  groundOuts groundOutsToAirouts  hitBatsmen  hitByPitch  hits hitsPer9Inn  holds homeAway  homeRuns homeRunsPer9  inheritedRunners  inheritedRunnersScored inningsPitched  intentionalWalks  losses   obp  outs  pickoffs pitchHand probablePitcher  rbi  runs runsScoredPer9  sacBunts  sacFlies  saveOpportunities  saves  shutouts stolenBasePercentage  stolenBases  strikeOuts  strikeZoneBottom  strikeZoneTop strikeoutWalkRatio strikeoutsPer9Inn               teamName  triples                        venue walksPer9Inn  whip  wildPitches winPercentage  wins
0     15.0    44.0    0.0          9.0         0.0                   0.0             0.0    Baltimore            0.0      day      2.0         8.0   6.00  2020-08-19T17:05:00Z            0.0           3.0          3.0           3.0         9.0                0.60         0.0         0.0  10.0        7.50    0.0     away       3.0         2.25               0.0                     0.0           12.0               0.0     1.0  .358  36.0       0.0         R    Tanner Roark  0.0   8.0           6.00       0.0       0.0                0.0    0.0       0.0                1.000          1.0        10.0             1.589          3.467               1.11              7.50      Toronto Blue Jays      0.0  Oriole Park at Camden Yards         6.75  1.58          0.0          .500   1.0
1     18.0    74.0    0.0          3.0         0.0                   0.0             0.0    Baltimore            0.0      day      5.0         8.0   4.00  2020-08-19T17:05:00Z            0.0           4.0          4.0           4.0        18.0                1.00         1.0         1.0  22.0       11.00    0.0     home       1.0         0.50               0.0                     0.0           18.0               0.0     2.0  .329  54.0       1.0         L    Tommy Milone  0.0  11.0           5.50       1.0       1.0                0.0    0.0       0.0                1.000          1.0        18.0             1.535          3.371               6.00              9.00      Baltimore Orioles      1.0  Oriole Park at Camden Yards         1.50  1.39          1.0          .333   1.0
2     14.0    59.0    0.0          2.0         0.0                   0.0             0.0       Boston            0.0      day      3.0         7.0   4.02  2020-08-19T17:35:00Z            0.0           3.0          3.0           3.0        14.0                1.00         0.0         0.0  17.0        9.77    0.0     away       2.0         1.15               0.0                     0.0           15.2               0.0     2.0  .311  47.0       0.0         R    Jake Arrieta  0.0   7.0           4.02       0.0       0.0                0.0    0.0       0.0                 .---          0.0        14.0             1.627          3.549               7.00              8.04  Philadelphia Phillies      0.0                  Fenway Park         1.15  1.21          2.0          .333   1.0
3      2.0    14.0    1.0          3.0         0.0                   0.0             0.0       Boston            0.0      day      1.0         5.0  22.50  2020-08-19T17:35:00Z            0.0           1.0          1.0           1.0         1.0                0.50         0.0         0.0   7.0       31.50    0.0     home       2.0         9.00               0.0                     0.0            2.0               0.0     1.0  .588   6.0       0.0         L       Kyle Hart  0.0   7.0          31.50       0.0       0.0                0.0    0.0       0.0                 .---          0.0         4.0             1.681          3.575               1.33             18.00         Boston Red Sox      0.0                  Fenway Park        13.50  5.00          0.0          .000   0.0
4      8.0    27.0    0.0          0.0         0.0                   0.0             0.0      Chicago            0.0      day      0.0         2.0   2.57  2020-08-19T18:20:00Z            0.0           1.0          1.0           1.0         7.0                0.88         0.0         0.0   6.0        7.71    0.0     away       0.0         0.00               0.0                     0.0            7.0               0.0     0.0  .222  21.0       0.0         R   Jack Flaherty  0.0   2.0           2.57       0.0       0.0                0.0    0.0       0.0                 .---          0.0         6.0             1.627          3.549               -.--              7.71    St. Louis Cardinals      0.0                Wrigley Field         0.00  0.86          0.0         1.000   1.0
5     13.0    65.0    0.0          6.0         0.0                   0.0             1.0      Chicago            0.0      day      2.0         6.0   2.84  2020-08-19T18:20:00Z            0.0           3.0          3.0           3.0        28.0                2.15         1.0         1.0  10.0        4.74    0.0     home       2.0         0.95               0.0                     0.0           19.0               0.0     1.0  .236  57.0       0.0         R      Alec Mills  0.0   6.0           2.84       0.0       0.0                0.0    0.0       0.0                 .000          0.0        14.0             1.627          3.549               2.33              6.63           Chicago Cubs      0.0                Wrigley Field         2.84  0.84          0.0          .667   2.0
6      NaN     NaN    NaN          NaN         NaN                   NaN             NaN      Chicago            NaN    night      NaN         NaN    NaN  2020-08-19T03:33:00Z            NaN           NaN          NaN           NaN         NaN                 NaN         NaN         NaN   NaN         NaN    NaN     away       NaN          NaN               NaN                     NaN            NaN               NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN       NaN       NaN             NaN  NaN   NaN            NaN       NaN       NaN                NaN    NaN       NaN                  NaN          NaN         NaN               NaN            NaN                NaN               NaN           Chicago Cubs      NaN                Wrigley Field          NaN   NaN          NaN           NaN   NaN
7      NaN     NaN    NaN          NaN         NaN                   NaN             NaN      Chicago            NaN    night      NaN         NaN    NaN  2020-08-19T03:33:00Z            NaN           NaN          NaN           NaN         NaN                 NaN         NaN         NaN   NaN         NaN    NaN     home       NaN          NaN               NaN                     NaN            NaN               NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN       NaN       NaN             NaN  NaN   NaN            NaN       NaN       NaN                NaN    NaN       NaN                  NaN          NaN         NaN               NaN            NaN                NaN               NaN    St. Louis Cardinals      NaN                Wrigley Field          NaN   NaN          NaN           NaN   NaN
8     13.0    92.0    0.0          8.0         0.0                   0.0             1.0  Kansas City            0.0      day      6.0        10.0   3.91  2020-08-19T21:05:00Z            0.0           4.0          4.0           4.0        24.0                1.85         0.0         0.0  25.0        9.78    0.0     away       1.0         0.39               0.0                     0.0           23.0               0.0     2.0  .327  69.0       0.0         R   Luis Castillo  0.0  12.0           4.70       0.0       1.0                0.0    0.0       0.0                 .000          0.0        31.0             1.589          3.467               3.88             12.13        Cincinnati Reds      1.0             Kauffman Stadium         3.13  1.43          0.0          .000   0.0
9     10.0    36.0    0.0          5.0         0.0                   0.0             0.0  Kansas City            0.0      day      0.0         0.0   0.00  2020-08-19T21:05:00Z            0.0           2.0          2.0           2.0        11.0                1.10         1.0         1.0   5.0        4.09    0.0     home       0.0         0.00               0.0                     0.0           11.0               0.0     0.0  .262  33.0       0.0         R     Brad Keller  0.0   0.0           0.00       0.0       0.0                0.0    0.0       0.0                 .---          0.0        10.0             1.681          3.575               2.00              8.18     Kansas City Royals      0.0             Kauffman Stadium         4.09  0.91          0.0         1.000   2.0
```

Comment: Amazing find @chitown88! This will be so helpful. =)  I will look into the requested info and hope to respond soon. Thanks for your time, sir. Can't thank you enough.